# How to resolve loading error

Tags: jspm

I am learning JSPM and trying to get it to work using the test code.

However, I have not been able to get this work.  The error I get in the console is:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:5172/none.js(…)
```

The network tab shows a 404 error on none.js.

This is the line of code:

```
import {bootstrap} from './bootstrap';
```

I don't understand why this would not be found.  The network tab shows that main.js is found an downloaded, but not bootstrap.   This makes no sense. This is the bootstrap file which is in the 'lib' directory.

Comment: What version of JSPM you are working on? Also few more details like what is the code in index.html, etc. would be helpful here

Comment: I found the actual issue which is that I had set the transpiler to "none".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jspm, then you should have globally and locally installed jspm, and then done `jspm init` to create your project and then `jspm install bootstrap`.  That should work.

See if this helps: https://github.com/caasjj/jspm-tut.git

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial. Don't forget to add 'jspm install css' to the instructions.